# Filter post style attribute

Tags: custom-field, css, the-content

Looking for a hook which enables filtering of a class within the post or content so i can add inline CSS using custom fields for posts on the home page.

Something like this -

```
add_filter( 'attr_entry', 'filter_post_html_tag' );
function filter_post_html_tag( $attributes ) {

    $color = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'background_color', true );
            
    $colors = $color ? $color : 'grey';

    $attributes['style']  = 'color:' . $colors . '';

    return $attributes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`post_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_class/) filter.
However, it depends on the theme you are using and how they used the loop

Comment: Does this allow me to filter the style attribute so i can add inline CSS? I'm not looking to add classes.

Comment: @Michelle No, for that you'll need to create your own function and edit the template file(s) to add that. There's no (or at least I am aware of) hook that lets you add your own attributes.

Comment: There is a style css filter but i forget what it is. Anyone clever?